# How to get rid of text before pie chart in Jupyter Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to make a pie chart from the data in this CSV file.
The problem is that it works but it displays text before the pie chart and I would like to get rid of it.

Also how can I scale the bar chart so it fits perfectly in the workbook?

```
#imports for pandas and numpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import*
from collections import OrderedDict
from collections import Counter

#Importing the file where I get the data from
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',delimiter=',', skipinitialspace = True)

df['artist genre'].value_counts()

genreArray = np.array(df['artist genre'])


keys = Counter(genreArray).keys()
values = Counter(genreArray).values()
#counts =Counter(genreArray)

plt.pie([float(v) for v in values], labels=[k for k in keys],
          autopct=None,frame=True)
```

Results:

```
([<matplotlib.patches.Wedge at 0x28d57bec160>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Wedge at 0x28d57bec6a0>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Wedge at 0x28d57becbe0>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Wedge at 0x28d57bf5160>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Wedge at 0x28d57bf56a0>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Wedge at 0x28d57bf5be0>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Wedge at 0x28d57bfc160>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Wedge at 0x28d57bfc6a0>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Wedge at 0x28d57bfcc88>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Wedge at 0x28d57c09208>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Wedge at 0x28d5796acc0>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Wedge at 0x28d57c09c50>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Wedge at 0x28d57c101d0>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Wedge at 0x28d57c10710>],
 [Text(0.801866,0.753002,'Pop'),
  Text(-0.646564,0.889919,'Hip Hop'),
  Text(-1.08052,-0.206119,'Electronic Dance Music'),
  Text(-0.753002,-0.801865,'Latin Pop'),
  Text(-0.273559,-1.06544,'R&B'),
  Text(0.172078,-1.08646,'Pop Rock'),
  Text(0.339919,-1.04616,'Electronic Music'),
  Text(0.468357,-0.99531,'Deep House'),
  Text(0.701166,-0.847565,'Reggaeton'),
  Text(0.946816,-0.559946,'Progressive House'),
  Text(1.04616,-0.339919,'Dance Pop'),
  Text(1.08052,-0.20612,'Electropop'),
  Text(1.09512,-0.103519,'Country'),
  Text(1.09946,-0.0345519,'Indie Pop')])
```

[image: This is the bar chart that is returned then]

Answer (score 2):

You can add a semicolon at the end of the `plt.pie(...);` call.